# Trouble Setting State in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I'm calling an API (in Node) from my react component (Stats.js)

This function getName is taking a passed in prop (called 'value')
in order to look up a value in MongoDB.  See code below:

```
/* Stats React Component --Stats.js*/
class Stats extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
       marketdata: [],
       value: '',
       name: ''
    }
    }


  componentDidMount() {
    const {value, name} = this.state;
    this.getName(value);
    this.getData(name);
   }

     getName = (value=this.props.value) => {
       value = value.replace(/"/g,"");
       console.log('Value', value);
       fetch(`/stats?ticker=${value}`)
      .then(res => console.log('Response', res))
      .then(results => {
         this.setState({
             name: results,
    })
    })

}

   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      this.setState({value: nextProps.value });
    }


   getData = (name=this.state.name) => {
    fetch(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/${name}/?convert=USD`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(results => {
     this.setState({
        marketdata: results,
     })
     })

     render() {
  const {marketdata} = this.state;



     return (
            <div className="App">
            {marketdata.map(data =>
              <div key={data.id}>
                <span>Price: {numeral(data.price_usd).format('$0.00')} </span>
                <span>24 Hour Volume: {numeral(data["24h_volume_usd"]).format('$0.0a')} </span>
                <span>Pct Change (24 Hrs): {(numeral((data.percent_change_24h)/100).format('0.0%'))} </span>
                <span>Market Cap: {numeral(data.market_cap_usd).format('$0.0a')}</span>
              </div>
            )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Stats;
```

As an example, this passed in prop (value) looks like this "BTC"--i can verify in developer console that the value of state is working correctly

I'm trying to set the state of the 'name' variable to the data returned from
the API lookup, the method called getName.

I can also verify in express that the data is being retrieved correctly on the backend.  This is my express file that is called by getName

```
/* GET coin stats.  stats.js */
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  let ticker = req.query.ticker;
  console.log(ticker);
  Stat.findOne({symbol:ticker})
    .then(function(result) {
      var stats = result;
      console.log(stats.name);
      res.json(stats.name);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('caught error', err.stack)
      res.send({ error: err })
    })
});
```

Note my data in the database looks like this: symbol: "BTC", name: "Bitcoin", thus when a user enters BTC i need name to set state to 'Bitcoin"

If I do a http://localhost:3001/stats?ticker=BTC is does indeed return "Bitcoin"

However for some reason the state of 'name' is not changing when a user inputs a value and my Stats.js component receives a new value.

Anyone see any problems here?

Comment: You'll need to debug the problem more. Does the correct value come back from the server? Is it in the correct format? What happens / what do you see for `results` when you step through the code receiving it statement by statement in the debugger? Fundamentally the `setState` call in `getUserName` is just fine.

Comment: Ok, i updated the code in the getName method to show where i'm logging.  The first console.log of 'value' is showing a blank so thinking that must be the issue---the console.log of the response is showing zero results and the url doesn't have the "BTC" on the end.  I'm stumped--because in dev tools--the state on the Stats component for value shows as "BTC" and when changed it updates correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getName` and `getData` are only called, in `componentDidMount` which is called only once. 
You need to call them when you update the value in `componentDidUpdate` too, when the state updates with the new value from `componentWillReceiveProps` function. Also provide a check in componentWillReceiveProps function before setting state

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if(this.props.value !== nextProps.value) {
      this.setState({value: nextProps.value });
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
    const {value, name} = this.state;
    this.getName(value);
    this.getData(name);
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) { 
  if(this.state.value !== prevState.value) {
      this.getName(this.state.value);
  }
  if(this.state.name !== prevState.name) {
      this.getData(this.state.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks--i'm getting a "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" on the `if(this.state.name !== prevState.state.name) `

Comment: Sorry for the typo: It should be `prevState.name`

Comment: hmm..not sure what's going on but made all those changes and now i get a `marketdata.map is not a function` error which is where my render statement ...so must mean the data isn't passing thru correctly i think?

Comment: so i removed the `if(this.state.name !== prevState.name) {
      this.getData(this.state.name);
  }`  from componentDidUpdate and it seems to be working now---only because there is no actual name being passed in to begin with--i think that makes sense right?  Thanks for your help!